# What does difficulty impact in Void Bastards?

Tags: void-bastards

There's five difficulties available to me in Void Bastards, ranging from "Easy Peasy" to "Hard Bastards". While those names are certainly amusing, the game doesn't give any detail on what the varying difficulty levels actually effect in game. I'm certainly open to just messing around to find out what difficulty works best for me, but it would be great to not need to go in blind when trying to figure out which difficulty I want play on.

What changes between the difficulty levels in Void Bastards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unfortunately can't give you an answer which breaks each level down exactly, but I did find the following.

[Blue Manchu, a Void Bastards developer, posted the following on the Steam forums:](https://steamcommunity.com/app/857980/discussions/0/1643164649210441360/#c1643164649210462937)

> We don't break it out as it changes a lot of parameters. Primarily amount of damage enemies do to you, but also ammo drops, oxygen amount, number of starmap hazards, speed at which security detects you and probably some other things that I've forgotten.

[And also this:](https://steamcommunity.com/app/857980/discussions/0/1643164649216890447/#c1643164649218677500)

> A list of things that change with difficulty (there may be more too):
>
> - Amount of damage you take from enemy shots, hazards, etc
> - Amount of food and fuel both on board ships and in the nebula
> - Oxygen
> - Response speed of gunpoints and watchers.
> - Ammo loot amounts
> - Care package amounts
> - Time enemies stay stunned
> - Type of entities and locations encountered in the nebula (whales, hermits, etc).

[There is also this thread, but it has far too much information to post here.](https://steamcommunity.com/app/857980/discussions/0/1643164649210620118/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't need a point-for-point breakdown, but it's great to have *some* idea what the difficulty changes, and this list is fairly detailed.